# How to Mount extended case-sensitive journaled volume on APFS directory, permanently if possible

Tags: mount, apfs, hfs+

Source:

```
/dev/disk0s3 

UUID=894D79A6-40BD-306A9784-BEBAB444B1A 

hfs, local, journaled case-sensitive
```

---

Destination:

/dev/disk1s1

UUID=F692F645-EE36-3CD6-AC09-BCD8FFCC6F3C

apfs, local, journaled not-case-sensitive

mountpoint= /Users

=====================

Asking for 1. foremost, a command line entry (I almost never reboot my iMac)

```
       2. & if possible, a script

       3. & if at all possible, a system modification to make this permanent
```